# How to Create,set,Read and Delete environment variable using C# and VB.Net programming languages

Tags: environment-variables

I want to create a environment variables using C# and VB.Net code and able to Read,Delete and Set values to the new created variable. help me with code to do this process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`
to create, modify or delete environment variable and
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`
for retrieve it.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2
To delete you set it to null.